# WebRTC - DataChannel - Suitable for mobile internet?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, nat, rtcdatachannel

I used this [code](https://github.com/JustGoscha/simple-datachannel), which is explained [here](http://www.justgoscha.com/programming/2014/03/07/simple-webrtc-datachannel-establishment-for-dummies.html) to create a webrtc datachannel connection without using any fancy libraries. Websockets are used for signaling.

Now, when I run the node app on my server, which has a global IP, I can connect with two browser instances through websockets. Both browsers are then able to connect via datachannels.

Now I replaced one browser instance by using my mobile phone browser (latest chrome browser) and tried the same. Sadly, no connection was engaged. When I use two 2 browser instances on by mobile phone, every works as well.

So, maybe there is something wrong with the signaling, if two browsers are not within the same machine, or **NAT traversal does not work for mobile phones with mobile internet**, which is what I suspect, but I'am not sure.

Can someone say for sure that mobile internet devices are *theoretically* able to NAT traverse ? (I do not know, how mobile providers setup their network topology)

Comment: I have successfully done numerous data channel connections and video calls from my Android phone on 4g and on wireless to other networked devices. Having good ICE servers is a must for any connection and you MAY have to have a turn server but I was able to connect from 4glte with only a STUN server.

Comment: So the quality of the STUN server as impact on traversal ? Alright, I'm going to test this with a STUN server running on my own global linux box. I though carrier grade NAT (symmetric NAT) could prevent hole punching. Good to hear, that you had luck!

Answer (score 1):

Devices connected through mobile networks are definitely able to traverse NATs, but it's a lot trickier and less likely to succeed.

You should look into using a TURN server as fallback when normal STUN is not sufficient for hole punching.

I found the following resources helpful for this purpose:

- https://blog.andyet.com/2015/01/14/turn-for-webrtc (mentions a few modules which let you run your own TURN server, difficult)
- https://www.twilio.com/stun-turn (lets you purchase TURN usage for a fee, easy)

Any service that's running in production **needs** a TURN server, or it'll be unreliable and flaky for users. Unless your application doesn't require exact point-to-point connectivity between two users. For example [WebTorrent](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent) is one such project where you only need to be able to connect to **some** peers, but not **specific** peers, for it to work.

Comment: Alright, I'm actually already happy, if I would know, that the code is not missing some important part. I thought that carrier grade NATs can prevent hole punching, so maybe it's really a mobile provider issue ? I'm sitting in Germany with H+ mobile internet with 1and1 as provider. Who knows ?